# use the c:out tag on a String

Tags: jsp, tags, javabeans

Inside my jsp page, I have a string I want to show, but it might contain '<' or some other character that I want to escape so it will not mess up the rest of the HTML.

I know c:out can do this, but as far as I understood, it can only work on bean properties, and not on a simple string.

Is there a way of doing something like

```
<c:out value="${myString}"/>
```

where myString is a simple java String defined in the scope of the page?

Or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: Where exactly does the string you want to display come from?  Is it defined in a "<% ... %>" block?

Comment: it's a dollar-sign, not a percentage-sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:out value="${myString}"/>
```

One way of having myString available is by having done `request.setAttribute("myString", ...)` somewhere before reaching the template.